# Meteor: getting image from cameras on mobile

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, camera

The mdg:camera package works impeccably on the desktop, but fails just as completely on the Android phone on which we tested.  First, there appears to be no way to switch between the front and rear cameras.  Also, the preview frame shows a still image of whatever the camera was pointing at when the button was pressed, making it impossible to frame the scene.

I found num3a:camera, which is based on mdg:camera, but the docs don't explain what added value it brings beyond that offered by mdg:camera.  In particular, I don't see any option to switch between the front and rear cameras.

Then there is num3a:canvas-camera, which is, sadly, "not yet usable".  This is based on the Cordova CanvasCamera plugin, which does claim to offer all the functionality we need (and more).  Sure enough, however, when we try this we get "window.plugin undefined".

Using CanvasCamera directly hasn't worked out very well, either.  The docs (here https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin ) seem to imply that we should call "app.initialize();" somewhere, but app is undefined, of course.  Otherwise, the CanvasCamera object is undefined, so nothing works... but I may be failing to understand how to do this properly.

Can somebody suggest a Meteor package besides those mentioned above?  Or am I just doing it all wrong?

Comment: Version of device you're testing with?

Comment: It's a Samsung Galaxy Note 3:
http://m.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_3-5665.php

Even if we get the camera to function properly on this device, we would still need a way to switch between the front & rear cameras.  Sadly, this option is not provided by mdg:camera.

Comment: That's not entirely true,  I am able to use the front camera in my project.  What's the Android version of the phone

Comment: But how do you switch between cameras?  Our phone is stuck on the front camera.
Android 4.4.2